# This jQuery works offline but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/koawatea.json?count=1&include_rts=1&callback=?", function(data)
    {
     $("#headertweet").html(data[0].text);
    });
</script>
```

It have created a test document that works offline.
But this does not work when I put it online (live or on my local XAMPP setup).

Can somebody tell me why, please?

Here's the CSS:

```
#headertwitterbox {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background:url(http://i48.tinypic.com/169ruab.jpg) no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 7pt;
}

#headertweet {
    width: 180px;
    height: 53px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="headertwitterbox" style="float:left;">
<div id="headertweet"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have Errors? You should also look at 1.1 version of the api.

Comment: I do not have errors. =S

Comment: [Here's a JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6SMnz/1/). It works fine there. Are you using an interesting version of jQuery?

Comment: where is the JavaScript defined? In the head?

Comment: Did you try to add https instead of http on your getJSON url?

Comment: @sharth Yeah, this is why I'm confused.

Comment: @epascarello Yep, it's in the head. I've tried both putting it in script tags and linking to an external JS sheet.

Comment: @Chad It was originally HTTPS, I changed it to HTTP to see if that would fix the problem, I must have left it that way when I posted the code here for help.

Comment: Could you post a link to an online version that does not work?

Comment: @Juhana Sure, I'll get it up tomorrow morning (about 10 hours), when I get to work.

Comment: @Juhana Here's a link for you: http://koawatea.co.nz/5327-2/

Comment: I thought you said there are no errors. I get `Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function` and three others.

Comment: Sorry, I was not getting any errors on my XAMPP version. I put it on this online version AFTER I had stated that, and also forgot to check the online version for errors.

But thank you for bringing this to my attention. I tried changing the "$" to "jQuery" on my XAMPP version and this did fix it. I'm not sure why it wasn't displaying as an error if this was what was causing it.

Comment: It's because you have `jQuery.noConflict();` a few lines before. It releases `$` for other libraries to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yep, it's in the head. I've tried both putting it in script tags and
>   linking to an external JS sheet.

That would be your problem. You are calling it before the element's are loaded so it probably is not finding the element because it has not been created by the time the response comes back. Place the script after the element `headertweet` OR call it on *document ready*.

After:

```
<div id="headertwitterbox" style="float:left;">
<div id="headertweet"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/koawatea.json?count=1&include_rts=1&callback=?", function(data)
    {
     $("#headertweet").html(data[0].text);
    });
</script>
```

In Head with doucument ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function () {
        $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/koawatea.json?count=1&include_rts=1&callback=?", 
            function (data) {
                $("#headertweet").html(data[0].text);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

---

**EDIT - Changed because you gave the link and the error is related to something else!**

In the sample link you have errors! You defined jQuery in no conflict mode, BUT you are using $! Change the $ over to jQuery!

Comment: Thanks, changing the "$" to "jQuery" did fix it. I did not downvote =S

Comment: Thanks. I solved a problem similar with above through epascarello's answer.